# How to optimize resources (images, json) version management

Tags: angularjs, json, git, version-control, resources

I'm actually working on an AngularJS app which consume a lot of independant resources. 
The code and the resources are versioned with Git, and the resources (images, html, json...) are organized in module by theme.

**Here is my problem :** The resources use a lot of disk space in our Git repo.

So do you know any free versioning tool more efficient than git to store this type of file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most text based files (HTML, json) should be fine with git. They won't take up too much space. For binary files, such as images, that are changed often you might want to consider using [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/). This should limit the space used by old revisions of binary files to the Large File Storage itself, not the development machines.

Comment: Just to add a bit more detail to this but Git is fantastic at handling changes to text files. i.e. JS, HTML, CSS. However it does not handle binary files well. i.e. images. This because it considers the entire file to have changed each time you make update the image. These no longer used images sit in your Git history forever and will be copied down when someone clones the repo.